# Just 1 icon out of several from my sprite will not show up

Tags: svg, icons, sprite

Hey guys fairly new to coding so forgive me. I took logos and made a sprite and inserted into my header. Everything works fine except the #chevron, it is the only one not showing up. If I use #quotes instead, the quotes icon shows up fine. I'm assuming it's a file issue but I checked the file and its fine.

Solutions I've tried;

- Remaking the sprite file etc
- Checking the original chevron.svg file (Its completely fine)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and update your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To anyone curios, I found the answer. My sprite file had no fill color in the file where for the symbol/logo that was messed up. Where the rbg values are for your logo add a your desired fill, I used a hex code.